# Complex derivative in terms of partial derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic. Now, if we write $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ with $u,v$ harmonic, is there a way to write the complex derivative $\frac{d f}{d z}$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $u,v$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: According to [Stein](http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Princeton-Lectures-No/dp/0691113858/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1376327241&sr=8-1&keywords=stein+complex+analysis), proposition 2.3 on page 12 says that if $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, then we have $f'(z_0)=\frac{\partial d}{\partial z}(z_0) = 2\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(z_0)$ where it has been defined previously that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is $d$?

Comment: Oops, that should read $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0)$, I'm writing up a more thorough answer currently.

Comment: Also, the fact that $u,v$ are harmonic isn't even necessary, for $f$ holomorphic implies that $u$ and $v$ are harmonic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First we will define
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
$$

I'm skipping some of the stuff in proposition 2.3 of [Stein](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691113858), however, the part I believe you will be interested in is the following,

If $f$ is holomorphic, then we have 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z_0) = 0
$$

and

$$
f'(z_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0) = 2\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(z_0).
$$

The Cauchy-Riemann equations give us 
$$
f'(z_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z_0) = \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z_0)\Rightarrow f'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z_0) + \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z_0)\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0).
$$

Now if we use the Cauchy-Riemann equations we see that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0) = 2\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(z_0)$. It is useful (and quite simple) to derive this and I suggest you do so to get more comfortable with Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 21):

$$\frac{d f}{d z}(z_0)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z_0) + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(z_0)$$.

Comment: Amazing how many pages some authors devote to hiding that fundamental equality from their readers.

Comment: What is the derivation? I am unconvinced by Kenny's answer.

Comment: Do you need the axiom of choice for this equation? I am pretty sure that at least a weak version is required

Comment: @ziv I think the axiom of choice is assumed

Answer (score 0):

If you look up The Cauchy-Riemann equations on Wikipedia you'll see how to use the chain rule to do this complex differentiation.