# Let $P$ be a complex polynomial such that $z \in \mathbb{R} \iff P(z) \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $deg P = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need some help with the following question:

Let $P$ be a complex polynomial such that $z \in \mathbb{R} \iff P(z) \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $deg P = 1$

There's also a hint:

Define $P = u+iv$ and show that either $v_y \le 0$ or $v_y \ge 0$ on the real axis.

I've managed to prove that. Then using CR equations I deduced that $u$ is monotone on the real axis which proves that $deg P$ is odd. I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: "I deduced that $u$ is monotone on the real axis" and hence, $P$ induces a bijection of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself.

Comment: But $z^3$ is also a bijection of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself

Comment: Yes, I was just about to say that.

Comment: Yes, but $P$ is supposed to have another property, which $z \mapsto z^3$ doesn't have.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was that I don't know how to use the fact that $P$ is such a bijection to prove that $deg$ $P = 1$

Comment: Ah. What do you know about polynomials of degree $d$ [$d > 0$]?

Comment: They have n roots and in this case all roots must be real, and since $P$ is a bijection of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself n = 1. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer Why not make that all into an answer, then?  Since, you know, it is one.  As for the question itself, when I was a student we liked to joke that "hint" means "this is something that could probably be used to get the answer, but need not be the most efficient, simple, beautiful, or even obvious way".  Why a particular hint failed at that was then a matter of some speculation: the professor didn't know? he's messing with you? he doesn't want you to use the good way, because this way makes you use the current material?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I would prove that $P$ is of degree $1$:

Say $P = a_nz^n + \cdots + a_0$, let $s > 0$ be a real number large enough that on the circle $\gamma$ with radius $s$ centered at the origin, the $n$-th degree term of $P$ dominates all the other terms together. Now parametrize $\gamma$ by $z(t) = se^{it}$, for $0\leq t < 2\pi$.

As $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, we have that $z(t)$ goes around $\gamma$, and $P(z(t))$ goes around the origin $n$ times. That means it hits the positive real axis at least $n$ times, and the negative real axis at least $n$ times. But $z(t)$ only hits the real axis twice (once on the positive side, and once on the negative side), so we *must* have $n = 1$, otherwise we have a value for which $P(z)$ is real, but $z$ is not.

Comment: @lhf I still don't use the hint, though.

Comment: This is also a natural answer in that it draws on something truly basic: the behavior of $z \mapsto z^n$ for large $n$.  This is a really nice question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n$ be the degree of $P$.

The hypothesis implies that all $n$ zeros of $P$ are real because $0$ is real. This implies that $P$ has real coefficients because $P(x)=a(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ implies $a$ is real by taking $x$ any real number that is not a root of $P$.

Now consider the equations $P(x)=c$ with $c$ real. The solutions must all be real, for every $c$. This means that the line $y=c$ cuts the graph of $P$ exactly $n$ times, counted with multiplicity. But this cannot happen if $n>1$ because $P$ goes monotonically to $\pm \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: This is not a complex analysis answer...

Comment: Please see my answer - I would have preferred putting as a comment to yours, but ran out of space... Basically isn't your "monotonically" analytic (i.e., depends on CR)?

Comment: I like this answer, and I think that using any complex *analysis* at all is overkill.  I don't understand @peter's comment: no, this is freshman calculus!  A little bit of detail is left to fill in here; in particular, one does not a contradiction this way when n = 2 (but no problem...).

Comment: @PeteL.Clark - I'm obviously missing something then - why do we have that $P$ is monotone? Where do we have that $P'$ does not change sign?

Comment: Oh, maybe this is the point: use calculus to show that for *any* nonconstant polynomial there is C such that if $x \geq C$ then $f$ is monotone and that if $x \geq -C$ then $f$ is monotone.  ("Use" is a little strong: this is a familiar fact.)  But then away from a bounded set, $f$ is at most two to one...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark - OK! Agreed. In my defense, I wanted to use the hint...

Comment: After @PeteL.Clark's comments, I see that you were probably not using the monotonicity of $P$, and modified my answer in consequence; by the way I liked your answer too (and had +1'd it)...

Answer (score 3):

As you and lhf both noted, $P(z)$ has real coefficients; from the hypothesis the $v$ vanishes exactly on the real axis, we know that (possibly after replacing $P$ with $-P$) $v$ is strictly positive (say) on the upper half plane and strictly negative on the lower half plane. Therefore $v_y\ge0$ on the real axis. By $CR$, we know that $u_x \ge 0$ on the real axis, as you said. Hence, viewing $P$ as a polynomial function from the reals to the reals, we know that $P$ is nowhere decreasing.  $P$ is not constant (otherwise the entire complex plane is mapped into the reals, contrary to hypothesis), so there is a $a\in {\mathbb R}$ such that $P'(a)$ is not zero. Let 
$c = P(a).$
Then, the polynomial $P(z) - c $ does not have a repeated root at $a$.
Hence, if $P$ is not of degree one, there is a  $b  \not=a$ (which must also be real, by the premise of the question) such that 
$$c = P(b) = P(a).$$

But this is not possible  (as $P$ is nowhere decreasing, and $P'(a)\not= 0.$)

Hence $P$ is of degree one.

Comment: Really like your solution. Would you mind explaining me simple assumptions you made at the beginning?

Comment: Thank you! lhf explains nicely why $P$ is real - so  are you asking about the sign of $v$? If so: the hypothesis is that $v$ vanishes exactly on the real axis, i.e., $\{z\mid v(z) \not= 0 \} = \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$. As $v$ is continuous, it must have constant sign when restricted to a  component of $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$. As $P$ is real, $P(\bar z)=\overline {P(z)} $,  and we must have that $v$ takes opposite signs on each component. So, WLOG (by replacing $P$ with $-P$ if necessary), we can assume that $v$ is positive on the top component, and negative on the bottom. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Hence, if one takes a vertical path going through the $x$-axis, $v$ must increase, so $v_y\ge 0$ along the $x$-axis.

Comment: Just what I was thinking. Thank you very much. Highly precise.

Comment: Why can $P$ not be constant along the real axis?

Comment: @student as I wrote in the answer above, if $P$ were constant along the real axis, $P$ would then be constant on the entire plane, contradicting the hypothesis that $P$ is real valued only on the real line. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I'm a little slow. Why does constant along the real axis imply constant on the entire plane?

Comment: @student Well, for instance, a *non-zero* poly $Q$ in 1 var with coeffs in a field has a finite number of roots - so if there exists a $c$ such that  $P(z)= c$ holds for infinitely many $z$, the poly $Q = P -c $ vanishes on an infinite set, and hence is identically $0$, so $P = c$ identically. Other style of argument: say $f$ is an analytic function on a connected open set $\Omega$, and that $f$ is constant on a subset of $\Omega$ with an accumulation point $a\in\Omega$. Then $f$ is constant (I looked up a real reference - Rudin theorem 10.18 real and complex analysis). OK?

Comment: @student I was sloppy in my first sentence in the preceding - " ... has a finite number of roots *in the field* " would have been better.... But do you follow?

Comment: Thank you very much. Right. Your first argument didn't occur to me. I like it! Thank you. Now I just have one last question: If we only know $u_x$ and $v_y$ why is it enough to say something about $P'$? Don't we need to know that $v_x \ge 0$ on the real line also?

Comment: I found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/466080/316333) and it seems to suggest that the derivative consists of $u_x$ and $v_x$.

Comment: @student In general, we have that $P = u + i v$, where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued.  But, as $P$ is real-valued when restricted to the $x$-axis, one has here that $v$ is identically zero on the real axis. Therefore, for real $x$, one has that  $P(x) = u(x,0)$, and that $P'(x) = u_x(x,0)$.

Comment: Oh yes, right. Thank you very much for your explanation!