# $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y), u$ and $v$ are differentiable. Is $f$ differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y), u$ and $v$ are real differentiable. Is $f$ complex differentiable?

I know that if $u$ and $v$ are continuous, then $f$ is continuous. How about the differentiability? If $f$ is differentiable, can we write $f'$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$?
Thanks!

Comment: Be careful. Are you asking if $f(z)$ is *complex differentiable* or *real differentiable*?

Comment: @TedShifrin Complex differentiable.

Comment: @Nan See the [Cauchy–Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) equations.

Comment: @TedShifrin Excellent question. May you please help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864449) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870926)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's incorrect.  Let me illustrate this with an example found in [some cv notes](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m43s12/public_html/notes/class4.pdf) <del>in the comments under @Rebellos's answer</del>.  (First example under Theorem 1 in the notes.)

> Let $f(z)=\bar{z}$ be defined on $\Bbb{C}$.  Then $f$ induces $u(x,y)=x$ and $v(x,y)=-y$.  Both of them are real differentiable, but $f$ is *nowhere differentiable (holomorphic)* since the [Cauchy–Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) equations is *never* satisfied.
>   $$\because u_x=1 \quad u_y=0 \qquad v_x=0 \quad v_y=-1 \\
> \therefore u_x(z) \neq v_y(z) \quad\forall\,z\in\Bbb{C}$$

To address the last prompt, $f'(z)=f'(x+iy)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)$.

- For a derivation of this identity, you may consult [another cv notes](http://www.math.psu.edu/yzheng/m597k/m597kLII2.pdf). (Equations (3)-(5))
- For the link between $$f'(z_0)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z_0)  =\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0),$$ you may see [another related Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/465989/290189).