# How is $f(z)=1_{xy \ne 0}$ not complex differentiable? I know $f(x,y)=1_{xy \ne 0}$ isn't real-differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, characteristic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 2.18

> [image]

---

- This is for complex analysis, but I have a feeling this might be answered mostly Calculus III. Thm 2.13 is Cauchy-Riemann.
- Re title: [On $\mathbb R^2-$ vs $\mathbb C-$ differentiability of $f, \Re(f)$ and $\Im(f)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870926/)

---

> 1. Is my understanding of the following solution right, and why/why not?

At a [Winter 2017 course in Oregon State University](http://math.oregonstate.edu/~deleenhp/teaching/winter17/MTH483/MTH483-HW1.pdf), there's a solution given: It seems to be saying that $f$ is not continuous and therefore conditions of Cauchy-Riemann do not hold because of some relationship between the continuity of $f$ and then parts of $f_x$ and $f_y$ and somehow the assumptions of C-R are equivalent to continuous differentiability.

Note: I assume the 'Theorem 2.15(b)' refers to an old edition, w/c is not relevantly different from the current edition, in w/c Cauchy-Riemann is in Thm 2.13.

> 2. Here is my solution. Where have I gone wrong, if anywhere, and why?

Rewrite $f(z) = f(x,y) = 1_{xy \ne 0}(x,y)$ s.t.

$$f_x(0,0) := \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{1_{00+\Delta x 0 \ne 0} - 1_{00 \ne 0}}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{0-0}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} 0 = 0$$

Similarly, $f_y(0,0) = 0$.

$$\therefore, f_x(0,0) = 0 = -i0 = -if_y(0,0)$$

Now $f_x(0,0)$ may be defined, but $f_x$ neither is continuous at $0$ nor exists on any disc centred at $0$ because $f_x$ does not exist along $x_0=0$:

$$f_x(0,y_0) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{1_{0y_0+\Delta x y_0 \ne 0} - 1_{0y_0 \ne 0}}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{1_{\Delta x y_0 \ne 0}-0}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta x} \ \text{, w/c dne.}$$

Similar holds for $f_y$ along $y_0 =0$.

$\therefore,$ Cauchy-Riemann holds at $z=0$ but $f$ is not differentiable at $z=0$ because $f_x$ is not continuous at $z=0$ because $f_x$ does not exist along $x_0=0$.

Comment: Partial derivative $f_x(z)$ does not exist at points $z=it$, $t$ small but non-zero. Neither does $f_y(z)$ when $z$ is a small non-zero real number. Therefore there is no open disk around the origin where those partial derivative would exist.

Comment: Why would you assume you have done something wrong??

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks! And that's what I did right?

Comment: @EricWofsey edited. thanks

Comment: Recall that being complex differentiable means the Cauchy--Riemann equations holds **and** that the function is real differentiable at that point. This function is not real differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks! Post as answer? ^-^

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Oh wait, you're stating something stronger than [Cauchy-Riemann Thm 2.13(a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26tS3.png)? From 2.13(a), if the $f(x,y)$'s partial derivatives didn't exist, then $f(z)$ isn't differentiable. But now you're saying that if $f(x,y)$ isn't differentiable then $f(z)$ isn't differentiable? As I recall, if $f(x,y)$ isn't differentiable, then $f(x,y)$'s partial derivatives exist and the converse is not true, so to change the conclusion in Thm 2.13(a) from '$f(x,y)$'s partial derivatives exist and C-R' to '$f(x,y)$ isn't differentiable and C-R' is to strengthen?

Answer (score 2):

That a function $f$ is complex differentiable at a point $z_0$ means that the derivative
$$
f'(z_0) = \lim_{\mathbb{C} \ni h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}
$$
exists.

Now, if $f$ (i.e. the real and imaginary parts of $f$) is real differentiable, and Cauchy-Riemann's equations are satisfied at $z_0$, this implies that $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$.

Note also, that existence of partial derivatives is not enough to conclude real differentiability!

Comment: Thanks mrf! I'll analyse later.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that being complex differentiable means the Cauchy--Riemann equations holds **and** that the function is real differentiable at that point. This function is not real differentiable at the origin.

With respect to the second comment: if the partial derivatives exist in a neighborhood of the point and are continuous, *then* the function is real differentiable, so this plus Cauchy--Riemann gives complex differentiablity, in light of the previous paragraph.

Comment: This seems a bit misleading. In particular, existence of partial derivatives does not imply real differentiability.

Comment: @mrf My bad. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks Pedro Tamaroff♦! I'll analyse later.